# How to Mute Sound in QWebEngineView PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

## Problem

I Want to Mute all sound QWebEngineView on Button click. And Also UnMute all Sound on another Button Click. I searched a lot on the internet but no one asked this type of Questions.

## Code

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        self.mutebtn=QPushButton('Mute this WebPage')
        self.mutebtn.clicked.connect(self.mutebrowser)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.mutebtn)
        self.unmutebtn=QPushButton('UnMute this WebPage')
        self.unmutebtn.clicked.connect(self.unmutebrowser)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.unmutebtn)
        self.browser=QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://youtu.be/B-wmrlzdK3k'))
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setMinimumSize(400,500)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def mutebrowser(self):
        # Code to Mute Sound in "self.browser"
        pass

    def unmutebrowser(self):
        # Code to UnMute Sound in "self.browser"
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.browser.page().`[`setAudioMuted()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#audioMuted-prop)

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot dude! Post this comment as Answer so that everyone will found this easily!

Comment: Honestly, there is really no need for an answer that would just contain a link to the documentation.

Comment: Okkh. Thanks Again!